# PHP Mail Function ERROR

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I m Facing problem with PHP mail Function. The problem is mail is being successfully sent but $body and  $ header is not working Properly

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['your_name'];

$email = $_POST['your_email'];

$phone = $_POST['your_phone'];

$subject = $_POST['your_subject'];

$msg = $_POST['your_message'];



$to = 'support@morelifelondon.net';

$subject = 'New Enquiry';

$body = $name '|' $email '|' $phone '|' $subject '|' $msg;

$header = 'From: $name <$email>';

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){
echo "Mail Sent";
}
else{
echo "Mail Failed";
}


?>
```

Comment: >>>>> http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 3):

Learn basic PHP:

```
$body = $name '|' $email '|' $phone '|' $subject '|' $msg;
```

This is a flat-out syntax error. You probably want

```
$body = $name . '|' . $email . etc....
              ^-----^---- etc...
```

And

```
$header = 'From: $name <$email>';
          ^--------------------^---
```

`'`-enclosed strings do **NOT** interpolate variables. Use `"` instead:

```
$header = "From: $name <$email>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this instead:

```
$body = $name . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $subject . '|' . $msg;

$header = "From: $name <$email>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$body = $name '|' $email '|' $phone '|' $subject '|' $msg;

$header = 'From: $name <$email>';
```

I see 2 errors in those 2 lines:

To concatenate string (join pieces of text) into 1 variable, you need a concat operator (in every programming language). For PHP this is the dot (.) .

So

```
$body = $name . '|' . $email . '|' . $phone . '|' . $subject . '|' . $msg;
```

Second: you are using variables between quotes.
This could work in 2 ways: or you split them out (preferable) or use double quotes (of use a function that does this for you).

```
$header = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>';
```

Comment: Why Table Format is not working 

                $abc = "<table>
              <tr><td>Name : - </td><td>".$name."</td> </tr>
              <tr><td>E-mail : - </td><td>".$email."</td> </tr>
              <tr><td>Phone : - </td><td>".$phone."</td> </tr>
              <tr><td>Subject : - </td><td>".$subject. "</td></tr>
              <tr><td>Message : - </td><td>".$msg." </td></tr>
              <tr><td><br></td></tr> 
              <tr><td>Thank You. </td></tr>
            
  </table>";

Comment: On first sight I don't see a problem with the functionality. That should work.

Comment: Functionality is working fine but the problem is the data which i m collecting from my FORM that should be display in table format but its not.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($_POST) on top of your code and check if the values are correct in the POST header?

Answer (score 0):

Too long messages can be truncated and not work properly.

Add `"\r\n"` after `$header = 'From: $name <$email>';`, like this:

```
$header = 'From: $name <$email>'."\r\n";
```

Also, if your `$msg` can be long, split it with carriage returns after 100 or so characters.